# Whether same output is obtained for the two queries

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra, relational-calculus, tuple-relational-calculus

Consider the following SQL Queries executed on the relation Employee:

> Employee (Eid, Ename, sal)

Eid is the primary key

Queries:

> S1:SELECT count (*) FROM Employee;
>
> S2: SELECT count (Eid) FROM Employee;

Will these queries return the same result or different results?

According to me, these queries should return same values.

But my solution manual claims that the values returned should be different. It says that S1 will also include results where Eid field is empty.

But according to me, the primary key field can never be empty. So, there will never be a case where Eid field will be empty. As this field will never be empty, the output of S1 and S2 should be equal.

Can anyone please tell me whether I am correct? If not, please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Obviously, it totally depends on your Eid whether it is unique and not null. If it is primary key the result will be same.

Answer (score 1):

> where Eid field is empty.

What do you mean by "empty"? Perhaps you mean 'null'?

What words *exactly* does your "solution manual" use? "empty" or "null"?

If the `Eid` field is `CHAR` there could easily be a row with `Eid` "empty" -- that is: zero length, or containing only space characters. `count(*)` and `count(Eid)` return the same value in that case.

If the `Eid` field is `NULLABLE` there could easily be a row with `Eid` null. `count(*)` will include that row, whereas `count(Eid)` will not.

Usually fields in keys are expected to be `NOT NULL`. Some vendors' implementations of the SQL standard insist on `NOT NULL`. But some don't. It is good practice to make key fields `NOT NULL`. Presumably your manual is getting you to think about why.